# Expression to Sum on DataSet field in Textbox for SSRS2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have what I thought was a very basic SSRS scenario. I have two datasets in my SSRS 2008 report; dsMTD and dsYTD. They both contain the same columns, the only difference is the SQL statement that fills them both (but I don't imagine that's really relevant to the problem).

I have a textbox on my report, and I wanted to show the SUM of a certain column within the report. I tried to make my expression as follows:

```
=Sum(Fields!cost.Value, "dsMTD").ToString()
```

This works fine in SSRS 2005, but the expression in SSRS2008 gives an error of "Unknown Collection Member" on the field reference in my expression.

Am I not doing something right? I've recently installed CU6 for SQL Server 2008 on my machine, and wonder if that has changed something?

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore this. The error is just misleading I assume. At first I was running and my dataset actually had no rows, which explained why a value wasn't coming back. I intially thought this was connected to the "Unknown Collection Member" error, but when trying to a different dataset that does have data, I still get that error, but also get the correct value.

I'll try and ask for help on things that actually are wrong next time!